# React/Recoil: once state is set in the main app, cannot be set again inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

After I set the state from the loadable within the App.js file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useRecoilState, useSetRecoilState, useRecoilValueLoadable } from 'recoil';
import './App.css';
import { Point } from './components/Point';
import { FocusState } from './context/FocusState';
import { ItemListState } from './context/ItemListState';
import { RootState } from './context/RootState';
import { DataState } from './context/DataState';

function App() {
  const setFocusState = useSetRecoilState(FocusState);
  const setItemListState = useSetRecoilState(ItemListState);
  const [rootState, setRootState] = useRecoilState(RootState);
  const dataStateLoadable = useRecoilValueLoadable(DataState);

  switch (dataStateLoadable.state) {
    case 'hasValue':
      let dataState = dataStateLoadable.contents;
      let {root, focus, items} = dataState;
      setFocusState(focus);
      setItemListState(items);
      setRootState(root);
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Point key={rootState} id={rootState} depth={0} />
        </div>
      )
    case 'loading':
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
      )
    case 'hasError':
      throw dataStateLoadable.contents;
    default:
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Calling the `setFocusState` function from within the `Point` component doesn't seem to work:

```js
export const Point: React.FC<{id: string, depth: number}> = ({id, depth}) => {
    const pointRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [focusState, setFocusState] = useRecoilState(FocusState);
    const [itemState, setItemState] = useRecoilState(SingleItemStateFamily(id))
    const parentPoint = useRecoilValue(SingleItemStateFamily(itemState.parent));
    const grandparentPoint = useRecoilValue(SingleItemStateFamily(parentPoint.parent));

    const setCursor = () => {
        // mignt be null
        const node = pointRef.current;
        let range = document.createRange();
        let sel = window.getSelection();

        if (node !== null && node.childNodes.length > 0 && focusState.id === id) {
            console.log(node, node.childNodes, focusState)
            // select a range first
            range.setStart(node.childNodes[0], focusState.cursorPosition);
            range.setEnd(node.childNodes[0], focusState.cursorPosition);
            // perform selection
            sel?.removeAllRanges();
            sel?.addRange(range);
            node.focus();
        }
    }

    const handleChange = (evt) => {
        let newState = {...itemState};
        newState.content = evt.currentTarget.innerHTML;
        setItemState(newState);
    }

    const handleKeyEvent = (evt) => {
        switch (evt.key) {
            case "ArrowUp":
                evt.preventDefault();
                console.log("Shift focus to item above", parentPoint.children, itemState.id, parentPoint.children.indexOf(itemState.id));
                // if it is the first child of a parent, shift focus to the parent
                if (parentPoint.children.indexOf(itemState.id) === 0) {
                    console.log("Shift focus to parent")
                    setFocusState({id: parentPoint.id, cursorPosition: focusState.cursorPosition});
                    console.log(focusState);
                }
                // else, go to the next highest sibling
                // the cursorPosition should be min(focusState.curpos, newPoint.content.length)
                else {
                    console.log("Shift focus to previous sibling")
                    setFocusState({
                        id: parentPoint.children[parentPoint.children.indexOf(itemState.id)-1],
                        cursorPosition: focusState.cursorPosition
                    });
                    console.log(focusState);
                }
                break;
            case "ArrowDown":
                evt.preventDefault();
                console.log("Shift focus to item below", parentPoint.children, itemState.id, parentPoint.children.indexOf(itemState.id));
                // if it is the last child of a parent, shift focus to the parent's next sibling
                if (parentPoint.children.indexOf(itemState.id) === parentPoint.children.length - 1) {
                    console.log("Shift focus to parent's next sibling")
                    setFocusState({
                        id: grandparentPoint.children[grandparentPoint.children.indexOf(parentPoint.id) + 1],
                        cursorPosition: focusState.cursorPosition
                    })
                }
                // else if it has any children, shift focus to the first child
                else if (itemState.children.length > 0) {
                    console.log("Shift focus to first child")
                    setFocusState({
                        id: itemState.children[0],
                        cursorPosition: focusState.cursorPosition
                    })
                }
                // else, go to the next lowest sibling
                else {
                    console.log("Shift focus to next sibling")
                    setFocusState({
                        id: parentPoint.children[parentPoint.children.indexOf(itemState.id)+1],
                        cursorPosition: focusState.cursorPosition
                    });
                }
                break;
            case "Tab":
                evt.preventDefault();
                if (evt.shiftKey) {
                    console.log("Dedent item");
                } else {
                    console.log("Indent item");
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    const handleBlur = (evt) => {
        let sel = window.getSelection();
        let offset = sel?.anchorOffset as number;
        setFocusState({
            id: focusState.id,
            cursorPosition: offset
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setCursor();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, [])

    return (
        <ul className="point-item">
            <li>
                <ContentEditable onChange={handleChange}
                    html={itemState.content}
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyEvent}
                    innerRef={pointRef}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                />
            </li>
            {itemState.children.map((child_id: string) => (
                <Point key={child_id} id={child_id} depth={depth+1}/>
            ))}
        </ul>
    )
}
```

When I add `console.log(focusState)` to the relevant parts of the switch statement within function `handleKeyEvent`, it shows that every time `setFocusState` is called from within the Point component, nothing changes and the value of `focusState` remains the same value as the initial setting. I am guessing this is why `setCursor` doesn't get called via useEffect.

Would anyone be able to advise what is going wrong here? What would need to be changed for

1. `setFocusState` to actually modify the value of `focusState` when called from within the `Point` component
2. For that to result in an actual modification of the cursor position via `setCursor`

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you log `focusState` right after setting it, you won't even log the new value because:

1. the `Point` component is rendered with `focusState`' old value (let's call it the #1 value)
2. you add an effect that calls `setCursor`, the effect has empty array dependencies it gets called but it won't get called again
3. you set `focusState` (to a #2 value) into the handler. Contextually, you log it hoping it contains the new value but...
4. since you set `focusState` the component re-renders to render with the new `focusState` value (#2)
5. your effect doesn't call `setCursor` because it doesn't depend on `focusState`

I think that this is your problem

Did you add the `// eslint-disable-next-line` for the sake of asking this question or because you'd like to avoid calling `setCursor` every time the reference to `setCursor` is new (at every render)? If the latter, please consider refactoring it to

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // mignt be null
  const node = pointRef.current;
  let range = document.createRange();
  let sel = window.getSelection();

  if (node !== null && node.childNodes.length > 0 && focusState.id === id) {
      console.log(node, node.childNodes, focusState)
      // select a range first
      range.setStart(node.childNodes[0], focusState.cursorPosition);
      range.setEnd(node.childNodes[0], focusState.cursorPosition);
      // perform selection
      sel?.removeAllRanges();
      sel?.addRange(range);
      node.focus();
  }
}, [id, focusState])
```

and removing the `setCursor` function at all.

---

Please note: this answer could be incomplete, please update the question with a playable CodeSandbox to fix definitely your problem.